# Splitting a CSV File Starting at row 28

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a file that has the column headers in rows 1-28, and then has the data starting at row 29. The data in row 29 is pipe delimited. I've tried the following, which didn't work:

`pd.read_csv(file_name, sep='|', index_col=False)`

Any ideas?

Comment: You mean **column**, not **row**. Is the separator for columns 1..28 comma?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [skiprows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv):

`pd.read_csv(file_name, sep='|', skiprows=28)`